# How to implement atomicity when working with webhooks in node?

Tags: node.js, express, stripe-payments, webhooks, atomic

I am working on a MERN application. I am trying to implement a stripe subscription in it.

Whenever a user tries to pay using the stripe checkout session the webhooks route is invoked and the database is updated according to the event type.

Here is my webhook controller code:

```
export const postStripeWebhook = async (req: ExtendedRequest, res: Response) => {
    
    //code to determine the eventype from the stripe signature.

    switch (eventType) {
        case "checkout.session.completed":
            subscription = event.data.object;
            
            await prisma.users.update({
            where: {
                id: subscription.metadata.userId,
            },
            data: {
                stripeUserId: subscription.customer,
                subscriptionStatus: true,
            },
        });

        break;

        //other events type

    }

    res.sendStatus(200);
};
```

As one can see when the customer pays for the product, stripe sends a `checkout.session.complete` event. On receiving this event the `subscriptionStatus` of the customer is updated in the database and the product is provisioned to the user.

But what if an error occurs while updating the database? Now the user will be left with a situation where his account has been deducted with the subscription money but since the database is not updated he has not provisioned the product.

According to me, this situation can be eliminated if the whole process is made atomic i.e if the database does not change send the deducted amount to the user.

But I don't know whether this is the right way to tackle this problem. Also I don't know how to perform atomic operations in node.js.

Please guide me with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is pretty simple: as the webhook is still a request, in case of any failure in the processing of it, you should return statu 5xx. In such case, Stripe will retry the webhook in some time and you will have another chance at handling it properly